# Find Nearby Users in Android

Tags: android

display a list of nearby users of my app Lets say a list users which are currently within 1 mile or 2 miles radius and are currently using my app.

App will update the list when user clicks a Refresh button.

what exactly process of finding available nearby users.
somebody please guide me

thanks.......
display a list of nearby users of my app Lets say a list users which are currently within 1 mile or 2 miles radius and are currently using my app.

App will update the list when user clicks a Refresh button.

what exactly process of finding available nearby users.
somebody please guide me

thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

From Android end you have to do:
you have an IntentService which post location of the user to the server for a certain period of time returns the list of users who are in the radius you define.

to get User location follow googleApiClient: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

And prepare a recycler view to show this result. Send a local broadcast from intent service to tell the activity containing recycler view to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Let every device regularly send it's GPS location to a server, e.g. once a minute.

Whenever a user clicks the refresh button send a request to the server.

The server has to respond with a list of IDs and GPS locations of users within the range of the user.

You could also do this on one synchronous post request:

```
POST /update_location HTTP/1.1 
Host: example.com 
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: ...

{
    ID: "foo",
    location: "-121.45356 46.51119"
}
```

And a server response like this:

```
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: ...

{
    ["bar", "-121.45346 46.51129"],
    ["baz", "-121.45353 46.51121"]
}
```